# HashSet<int>.Add(int) doesn't accept the parameter of boxed int

Tags: c#

I have the following function. The function will always be passed the parameter of `k` which can be converted to `keyType`.

```
void F(object k, Type keyType) // keyType is from runtime. cannot be generic
{
    object kvalue = Convert.ChangeType(k, keyType); //boxed int as expected
    dynamic hs = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(HashSet<>).MakeGenericType(keyType)); 
    hs.Add(kvalue); // Runtime error
    //....
}

// Setup for testing, not real usage.
object o = 10m; // decimal
var t = typeof(int); // will get the type at runtime. 

// Call the function
F(o, t);
```

However, the above code will get the runtime error of:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'The best overloaded method match for '`System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<int>.Add(int)`' has some invalid arguments'

Changing

```
dynamic hs = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(HashSet<>).MakeGenericType(keyType));
```

to

```
//dynamic hs = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(HashSet<dynamic>));
var hs = new HashSet<dynamic>();
```

can resolve the problem. Is there any other way?

Comment: Did you try HashSet<keyType>

Comment: Why do you need Activator.CreateInstance to create a new Hashset?

Comment: @jdweng It will not compile. keyType is an instance of `Type`.

Comment: Could you just make the `F` method generic?

Comment: `HashSet<dynamic>` is just `HashSet<object>`

Comment: @devNull, No it cannot be a generic method.

Comment: I've edited title to make it clear what you trying to add to the HashSet ("object {int}" is very confusing term for "boxed int"). I would recommend re-wording the title rather than simply reverting if you disagree with my change.

Comment: @ca9163d9 the example you've provided is somewhat misleading since you explicitly pass `typeof(int)` to `F()`, implying that you know the type at compile-time. Which conflicts with your comments stating that the type is only known at runtime

Comment: @devNull, I've updated the question. I gave the code for testing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Convert.ChangeType` returns an instance of `object`. There's no `Add(object)` method defined on `HashSet<int>`, only `Add(int)`.

Try the following using expression:

```
void F(object k, Type keyType)
{
    var hsType = typeof(HashSet<>).MakeGenericType(keyType);
    object hs = Activator.CreateInstance(hsType);
    var kvalue = Convert.ChangeType(k, keyType);

    Expression.Lambda<Action>(
        Expression.Call(
            Expression.Constant(hs, hsType),
            "Add",
            Type.EmptyTypes,
            Expression.Constant(kvalue, keyType))
        ).Compile()();
}
```